# Why does Http error 500.0 "ANCM In-Process Handler Load Failure" happen for debugging any VS projects with IIS Express that end in "dotnet"?

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, iis-express

For a while, I could not figure out why my test application named "myappdotnet" would not debug in Visual Studio (2019) with IIS Express. When I would try to run it, I would get this error in the browser:

```
HTTP Error 500.0 - ANCM In-Process Handler Load Failure
```

I discovered that it's related to the name of the project: "myapp**dotnet**.csproj". I found that *any* project name I created that ends with **dotnet** would cause this error 500.0. Removing the **dotnet** from the name, such as "myapp.csproj", allowed debugging with IIS Express without the error.

Why is that the case? Are those ending characters reserved? Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues is the right place for such.